# Node.js как серверная основа для мультиплеерной игры

Tags: node.js, javascript, разработка-игр, сервер

Привет. 
Интиресует данная технология, как она ведет себя в случае сервера для игры? Клиент скорее всего будет в браузере и на андроиде.

Как архитектурно вписыватся нода под данную задачу. Возможно ли в реальном времени взаимодействие двух браузерных клиентов? Есть ли утечки памяти.

Comment: отлично ведёт, в чём вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос в том, как архитектурно вписыватся нода под данную задачу. Возможно ли в реальном времени взаимодействие двух браузерных клиентов? Есть ли утечки памяти.
Пожалуй вынесу это в вопрос.

Comment: какой у вас опыт с серверным js-кодом? если шарите, никаких утечек не будет, а реал-тайм будет.

Начните, и когда возникнут проблемы, здесь помогут их решить, а пока что вопросу здесь не место. Ах да, прекрасно вписывается

Comment: @Spectre - по поводу утечек чистая правда, ни единого раза не было.

Comment: Спасибо, вы мне помогли. ;)

Answer (score 5):

- "как она ведет себя в случае сервера для игры?" - как вы напишите код, так и будет себя вести.
- "Как архитектурно вписыватся нода под данную задачу" - как выстроите архитектуру так и впишется
- "Возможно ли в реальном времени взаимодействие двух браузерных клиентов?" - да
- "Есть ли утечки памяти" - в "нативных" модулях их нет, к тому-же, как, надеюсь, вы прекрасно знаете - V8 имеет просто гениальный сборщик мусора, соответственно нужно очень сильно постараться, что-бы получить неуловимую утечку.

---

Если же вы не совсем верно сформулировали вопрос и просто хотели узнать можно ли уже использовать node.js для игрового сервера уже сейчас, то ответ - да, можно.

Comment: И вам тоже спасибо за ответ.